Azure CLI Bicep throwing error on MacBook M3
I'm on a new MacBook Pro M3 and installed Azure CLI using Homebrew as follows:
brew install azure-cli
brew update && brew install python@3.11 && brew upgrade python@3.11
brew link --overwrite python@3.11
When I run az bicep --help it works fine
When I run az bicep version or any other command like az bicep upgrade I get this:
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
[Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/leejohnson/.azure/bin/bicep'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.61.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 233, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.61.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 664, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.61.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 731, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.61.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 701, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.61.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 334, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.61.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
    return op(**command_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.61.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/resource/custom.py", line 4810, in show_bicep_cli_version
    print(run_bicep_command(cmd.cli_ctx, ["--version"], auto_install=False))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.61.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/resource/_bicep.py", line 94, in run_bicep_command
    installed_version = _get_bicep_installed_version(installation_path)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.61.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/resource/_bicep.py", line 275, in _get_bicep_installed_version
    installed_version_output = _run_command(bicep_executable_path, ["--version"])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.61.0/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/resource/_bicep.py", line 327, in _run_command
    process = subprocess.run(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1955, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/leejohnson/.azure/bin/bicep'


xcode-select --install try  this command and try other commands

That was already done

The error message you are seeing indicates that there is an issue with the Bicep executable file that the Azure CLI is trying to run. Specifically, the error message "Exec format error" suggests that the file format of the Bicep executable is not compatible with your system architecture.
Uninstall and reinstall again
brew uninstall azure-cli
rm -rf ~/.azure/bin/bicep
brew update && brew install azure-cli

@VenkatV that worked. Can you add it as an answer and I'll accept it please.


Azure CLI Bicep throwing error on MacBook M3

The error you encountered is due to an issue with the Bicep executable file that the Azure CLI is trying to run. Specifically, the error message Exec format error indicates that the file format of the Bicep executable is not compatible with your Mac system architecture.
To resolve this issue, you can try uninstalling and reinstalling the Azure CLI using the below commands.
 brew uninstall azure-cli
 rm -rf ~/.azure/bin/bicep 
 brew update && brew install azure-cli

Reference: Install with Homebrew
